# Are jython & coldfusion compatible?

Tags: java, coldfusion, jython

Are jython & coldfusion compatible? I mean, can I run both at the same time without trashing my server? Are there any overlapping conflictions with java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Jython and coldFusion will open a new instance of the JVM. Obviously you will need to manage memory accordingly.

By having two separate instances, you won't have any trouble, and it can't possibly "trash" your server. I would however recommend that you make sure you have enough memory, so you don't get the nasty **Out-of-memory errors**.

Running Jython and ColdFusion would be pretty much the same as having a multi-instance ColdFusion install, and you basically run through the same risks (i.e. not having enough memory)

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks! maybe this isn't the best idea then.